# ExtJS 6.6.0 Modern Toolkit MultiSlider

Tags: extjs

I am using ExtJS 6.6 Modern toolkit for my application.

I have a requirement to use a slider with two sliding buttons like we have in multislider in Classic toolkit (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.slider.Multi.html)

Single slider is available in modern toolkit.(https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.slider.Slider.html)

Please, anyone, suggest how can I create the multi-slider in the modern toolkit?

Answer (score 0):

Modern slider is multi-slider capable, just add the values config - values: [25, 50, 75].